# how to disable drag and drop the local files into html in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

In my project,which based on cef,users want to disable drag and drop local files to the chrome,but in my html users can drag and drop the html elements（e.g.images, I use html5 drag and drop function,show as the following:

```
$("body").unbind("dragstart"); 
$("body").unbind("drop");
```

the issue is that I can't drag and drop the elements in the html,but the effect what I want is that I just don't want to drag and drop local files into html.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking for [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) functionality?

Comment: I mean dragging and dropping the local file to the html in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing default on mousedown event:

```
<div onmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">DEMO</div>
```

OR

```
 <div onmousedown="return false">asd</div>
```

OR

```
<BODY ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
```

Refer this link in that there is detailing of disable dragging of images and text selection in webpages [disable dragging of images and text selection](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_disable_dragging_of_images_and_text_selection_in_web_pages) which will help you to do for all the elements.